# Sum individual elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sum a list of "individual" elements in a list. I have seen a lot of posts using sum but these only sum the entire list not the individual numbers within the list. This is typically used in numerology and therefore needs to sum and resolve each element to it's base 9 equivalent.

Current result:

```
numsum = [1, 23, 45, 76, 123]
output = sum(numsum)
print(output)

Output:  268
```

Required result:

```
output: [1, 5, 9, 4, 6]
```

I have tried using for loops but no real success. Anyone know what the most pythonic way to do this is?

Comment: "I have tried using for loops". Please post the said `for` loops so we can help see what may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to sum the **digits** of each number.

You could use an intermediate conversion to string within a list comprehension:

```
numsum = [1, 23, 45, 76, 123]

out = [sum(map(int, str(n))) for n in numsum]
```

A more numerical approach might be to use a repeated division by 10:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    SUM = 0
    while n>0:
        n, mod = divmod(n, 10)
        SUM += mod
    return SUM

out = [sum_digits(n) for n in numsum]
```

output: `[1, 5, 9, 13, 6]`

##### recursive approach:

if the number must be reduced until it is a single digit (`76` -> `13` -> `4`), you can transform the `sum_digit` function into a recursive one:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    SUM = 0
    while n>0:
        n, mod = divmod(n, 10)
        SUM += mod
    return SUM if SUM < 10 else sum_digits(SUM)

out = [sum_digits(n) for n in numsum]
```

output: `[1, 5, 9, 4, 6]`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and numerical approach! When I try to run either of these i get the error "'int' object is not iterable". Any idea why? Assuming this list is an int object?

Comment: "*Assuming this list is an int object*" -> a **list** cannot be an **int**. What is `type(numsum)`?

Comment: ran a print type and it seems to be <class 'int'>

Comment: OK, so what is `print(numsum)`? In your example `numsum` is a list, why is it an integer now? You're not showing us the same code as your used in your question.

Comment: @mozway I think he wants [1, 5, 9, 4, 6] rather than [1, 5, 9, 13, 6]

Comment: @Stuart well spotted! I hadn't seen that. Then we need a recursive approach. I'll update

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to sum the digits of every number in list?

try:

```
output = [sum(int(digit) for digit in str(number)) for number in numsum]
```

Go from int to str and back to int